# Prove that the $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$

Tags: aes, finite-field

I am new to this field. I am doing some cryptography course and have encountered $\text{GF}(2^8)$ in the famous AES algorithm. Although I do not have a strong relevant math background with this stuff(ring/field), I am really interested in it. My textbook has a question which says to prove that:

$$x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.
I am stuck at this point where I don't have much intuition about proving irreducibility over the whole $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. 
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Definition:** A non-constant polynomial is said to be **irreducible** if it is cannot be factored into a product of two non-constant polynomials. In other words; if $p(x) = q(x)t(x)$ and it is irreducible then either $q(x)$ or $t(x)$ is a constant polynomial.

One way to prove that is $p(x) = x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\operatorname{GF}(2)[x]$ is checking the divisibility by the lower degree irreducible polynomials. First degree 1, then degree 2, then degree 3, and degree 4 will be enough to determine since a degree 8 can be factored into two polynomials with possible degrees as $1\cdot 7,2\cdot 6, 3\cdot 5$, and $4 \cdot 4$.

Below all the arithmetic is performed on $\operatorname{GF}(2)[x]$

1. degree polynomials are $x$ and $x+1$. We can check the divisibility by setting $p(0) \stackrel{?}{=} 0$ or $p(1) \stackrel{?}{=} 0$. $p(0) = 1 \neq 0$ and also $p(1) = 1 \neq 0$. Therefore degree one polynomials doesn't divide $p(x)$. This is by the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) and here a [nice proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1850934/338051) in Math.SE.
2. degree polynomials, where we have four polynomials;

\begin{align}
 & x^2+x+1\\
 & x^2+x \\
 & x^2+1\\
 & x^2\\
 \end{align}

Let see why $x^2+1$ is not irreducible;

\begin{align}
(x+1)\,(x+1)&=x\,(x+1)+1\,(x+1)&&\text{by distributivity}\\
  &=x^2+1\,x+1\,x+1&&\text{.}\\
  &=x^2+(1+1)\,x+1&&\text{.}\\
  &=x^2+(0)\,x+1&&\text{since the coefficients are in }\operatorname{GF}(2)\\&=x^2+1
\end{align}

with a quick check that only $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible. To see that $p(x)$ is not divisible by $x^2+x+1$ perform division and look for the remainder. One can use this Sage script

```
R = PolynomialRing(GF(2),'x')
x = R.gen()
p = x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1
q = x^2 + x + 1
p.quo_rem(q)
```

the output is $(quo = x^6 + x^5 + x^3, rem = x + 1)$, . i.e cannot divide.

3. degree irreducible polynomials

\begin{align}
 & x^3 + x + 1 \\
 & x^3 + x^2 + 1
 \end{align}

4. degree irreducible polynomials

\begin{align}
 & x^4 + x + 1 \\
 & x^4 + x^3 + 1\\
 & x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
 \end{align}

These polynomials are generated with SageMath

```
degree=4
R = GF(2)['x']
for p in R.polynomials(degree):
     if p.is_irreducible():
         print(p)
```

To test all the division use the below

```
R = PolynomialRing(GF(2),'x')
x = R.gen()
p = x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1
lst = [ x^2 + x + 1,  x^3 + x + 1,  x^3 + x^2 + 1,  x^4 + x + 1 , x^4 + x^3 + 1, x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1]

for t in lst:
    print(p.quo_rem(t))
```

The output is

```
(x^6 + x^5 + x^3, x + 1)
(x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1, x^2)
(x^5 + x^4 + x^3, x + 1)
(x^4 + x, x^3 + x^2 + 1)
(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, x^3 + x^2)
(x^4 + x^3 + 1, x^3 + x^2)
```

Therefore $p(x) = x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\operatorname{GF}(2)[x]$

---

**Note 1:** low degree irreducible binary polynomials are important in Cryptography since they reduce the required arithmetic. Gadiel Seroussi, in 1998, made a huge list in [Table of Low-Weight Binary Irreducible Polynomials](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf). The list contains binary irreducible polynomials up to 10000 degrees.

**Note 2:**  [A014580](https://oeis.org/A014580) from
The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences contains a list of binary polynomials, encoded in binary, or evaluated when $x=2$. The $p(2)$ is 283.

**2, 3, 7, 11, 13, 19, 25, 31**, 37, 41, 47, 55, 59, 61, 67, 73, 87, 91, 97, 103, 109, 115, 117, 131, 137, 143, 145, 157, 167, 171, 185, 191, 193, 203, 211, 213, 229, 239, 241, 247, 253, **283**, 285, 299, 301, 313, 319, 333, 351, 355, 357, 361, 369, 375,...

The bolds irreducibles are listed in this answer.

**Note 3:**  [A001037](http://oeis.org/A001037) keeps the number of degree-n irreducible polynomials over $\operatorname{GF}(2)$. There are 18 in degree 8 and $p(x)$ among the lowest possible weight.

```
degree 1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8
count  1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18
```

and this can be counted by $$L_q(n) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{d|n} \mu (\frac{n}{d})q^d$$

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you so much for such a detailed and great explanation! I am much grateful to you for your kind help.

Comment: Addition: The question's $\Bbb Z_2$ is this answer's $\operatorname{GF}(2)$. The question's $\text{GF}(2^8)$ can be seen as the answer's $\operatorname{GF}(2)[x]$ restricted to polynomials with degree less than $8$, under the same addition law, and a different multiplication law: $r\cdot s$ in $\text{GF}(2^8)$ is defined to be $(r\cdot s)\bmod(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)$ in $\operatorname{GF}(2)[x]$. That modified multiplication is an internal law. It inherits associativity, commutativity, distributivity, neutral (the polynomial $1$). It is such that every element  except $0$ has an inverse.

Comment: @fgrieu I used to use $\Bbb Z_2$, nowadays I prefer $\operatorname{GF}(2)$ to honor the Galois. I wonder what would have been the science if he didn't die in the duel.