# AES and quantum computing

Tags: aes, quantum-computing

I am trying to understand the AES-256 encryption algorithm as it would be implemented on a gated quantum computer (actually, a simulator), and I am having some trouble understanding the theory behind it. The papers I read start with the ring of polynomials given by $F_2[x]/(1 + x + x^3 + x^6 + x^8)$. What is the significance of the polynomial $1 + x + x^3 + x^6 + x^8$? And how does this relate to $GF(2^8)$?

Comment: The title of the paper I'm reading is "Reducing the Cost of Implementing the Advanced Encryption Standard as a Quantum Circuit."

Comment: You might want to start with https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf - that tries to describe what AES is, including the multiplication operation that's confusing you.

Comment: [AES stick guide](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html)

Comment: Our canonical answer [Galois fields in cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2700/18298) and [Need help understanding math behind Rijndael S-Box](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/85670/18298) and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question, $F_2[x]/(1 + x + x^3 + x^6 + x^8)$ is isomorphic to $GF(2^8)$. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#Field_extension) for more info.

The polynomial $g(x) = 1 + x + x^3 + x^6 + x^8$ is irreducible over $F_2$, so the quotient is a field. The degree of the polynomial is 8, so it is a degree 8 algebraic extension of $F_2$. In other words, it is $F_{2^8}$.

Elements in $F_2[x]/(g(x))$ are equivalence classes of polynomials modulo $g(x)$.

This is a standard way to construct finite-degree algebraic field extensions.

By the way, I think AES actually has $x^4$ instead of $x^6$ in the polynomial. Not sure if that was a typo in your question or if you read it somewhere.

Comment: This was very helpful. I've been trying to factor the polynomial unsuccessfully over $_2$, so it's good to know that it is irreducible. How does one prove that that a specific polynomial is irreducible in $F_2$? I have very little intuition for $_2$. Also: you are indeed correct, the polynomial has $x^4$ instead of $x^6$. Is there a reason AES chose $1 + x + x^3 + x^4 + x^6$ instead of some other irreducible polynomail?

Comment: @RobertSingleton you can use [Rabin's test for irreducibility](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Rabin.27s_test_of_irreducibility). The choice of polynomial is just part of the standard.

Comment: You can find how to see that AES polynomial(s) is irreducible [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/77958/18298). The selection reason of low weight irreducible it this that reduces the calculation costs in the Finite Field.